# Instagram Automation without API allowed?

Tags: api, automation, instagram, bots

my two partners and me are about to create a software which automates liking, commenting and following for Instagram with the use of browser simulation (that means that we log into the account of the user through a browser, like google chrome). 
Is that kind of automation allowed by Instagram? And if not, is there a possiblity to get aproved?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's against their terms. I wouldn't bother nor risk it. Instagram is actively suing bot services. Look at the biggest bot service, Instagress - mysteriously shut down entirely.

They're also penalizing accounts that use bots. I run an agency and have seen my clients' engagement mysteriously drop by 50-90% for a seemingly endless amount of time after using bots.

I imagine the purpose of doing it with "browser simulation" like Chrome is to try to avoid detection? Good luck. Instagram is smart and of course has some of the best programmers in the world who know how to combat this type of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that such operation goes against [the terms of user of Instagram](https://help.instagram.com/478745558852511). Under "General Description", section 10:

> We prohibit crawling, scraping, caching or otherwise accessing any content on the Service via automated means, including but not limited to, user profiles and photos (except as may be the result of standard search engine protocols or technologies used by a search engine with Instagram's express consent).

Since you will be accessing content (and performing actions) via automated means, I would interpret that as a violation of this section.